# Why is Jquery sending "undefined=undefined" as my post parameters instead of sending the array data?

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays

I am attempting to send a javascript array to my web server for an ajax request.  Here is my code:

```
    function SearchTasksByTags() {
        // Get the list of tags currently chosen
        var tags = [];
        $('.tagit-choice input').each(function () { tags.push($(this).val()); });

        // If we have no tags, don't bother searching and just clear the current results
        if (tags.length == 0) {
            $('#tagSearchResults').empty();
            return;
        }

        // Retrieve the search results from the server
        $.ajax({ url: '<%= Url.Action("SearchByTags") %>',
            data: tags,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (html) {
                $("#tagSearchResults").empty().append(html);
            } 
        });
    }
```

The array is being formed correctly, as when I hit the `$.ajax()` call Chrome's developer tools show the tags object as being an array with 2 elements (all elements are just strings).

However, according to fiddler, the actual post parameters getting sent to the server are:

```
undefined=undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**
Console.Log shows:

```
console.log(tags)
["portability", "testing"]
undefined
```

Comment: `tags` is not an associative array, so I imagine jQuery is having a hard time building a query string from it. Although I'm surprised it treats it as `undefined`, that probably is the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What does a **console.log(tags)** say about the tags?

Try sending it like this:

```
data : ({tags : tags})
```

Comment: Added console.log output to question

Comment: This worked! (I forgot to refresh my page before attempting your solution)